# Pandas resample on given (arbitrary) datetimeindex (using e.g. nearest)

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to use `pandas.resample` with a given (arbitrary) DatetimeIndex (using e.g. `nearest` option with a given time window), instead of a the `rule` string for regular dates?

EDIT:

Example:

```python
dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01 12:00:00', '2000-01-03 13:00:00', '2000-01-05 15:00:00', '2000-01-09 10:00:00'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy': dates}, index=dates)
custom_dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-02 09:00:00', '2000-01-05 22:00:00', '2000-01-10 15:00:00'])
new_df = df.resample(custom_dates, method='nearest')
```

And `new_df` should now have as DatetimeIndex `custom_dates` and the columns from `df`.

Comment: Could you give a code sample of what you'd like to do if the functionality existed? I'm a little confused on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit late, but here is a solution that uses `reindex` which supports your desired `nearest` option:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01 12:00:00', '2000-01-03 13:00:00', '2000-01-05 15:00:00', '2000-01-09 10:00:00'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy': dates}, index=dates)
custom_dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-02 09:00:00', '2000-01-05 22:00:00', '2000-01-10 15:00:00'])

df.reindex(custom_dates, method='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(2, 'D'))
```

Output:

```
                    dummy
2000-01-02 09:00:00 2000-01-01 12:00:00
2000-01-05 22:00:00 2000-01-05 15:00:00
2000-01-10 15:00:00 2000-01-09 10:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks c_c! I didn't know about the tolerance keyword. Is it possible to get all neighbors in the tolerance radius?